# Firebase -> GoogleDataTransport -> GDTCCTNanopbHel

Tags: ios, firebase

I use Firebase pods

```
 pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

these pods download me GoogleDataTransport and this mark me a security error

```
Code Snippet

File Name -/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDT

CCTNanopbHelpers (copy 1).m

Method pb_bytes_array_t *GDTCCTEncodeData(NSData *data) {

....
44. pb_bytes_array_t *pbBytesArray = calloc(1,
PB_BYTES_ARRAY_T_ALLOCSIZE(data.length));
```

I tried to eliminate the googleDataTransport without success, there is some report of this vulnerability, I am lost in this topic of GoogleDataTransport, please if someone could guide me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Run `pod update` to update to a more recent version. The issue was addressed in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/4878